# Hibernate - Select Child and then join with Parent returns Parent with other children as well

Tags: java, sql, database, hibernate, hql

Maybe this is something basic but I can't get my head around this in hibernate.

I have to select some child records based on some conditions.

I have a parent entity :

```
 @Entity
    @DynamicUpdate
    @Table(name = "PARENT", catalog = "MYDB")
    public class Parent implements Serializable {
    ...
        private Set<Child1> child1 = new HashSet< child1>(0);
        private Set<Child2> child2 = new HashSet< child2 >(0);

...
        @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        public Set<Child1> getChild1() {
            return child1;
        }

    ...

        @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "parent")
        public Set<Child2> getChild2() {
            return child2;
        }
}
```

And the child1 as :

```
@Entity
@DynamicUpdate
@Table(name = "CHILD1", catalog = "MYDB")
public class Child1 implements Serializable {

...
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    public Parent getParent() {
        return parent;
    }
```

Now there is one to many relation here. One parent can have many child1 rows and many child2 rows.
My issue is selecting some child1 records with few conditions along with their parents but I do not want other children (child2) to be fetched along with the embedded parent record.

My sql query is to select the child along with its parent is :

```
Select c from Child1 pr join c.parent where c.parent.id IN :ids AND c.createdDate > :time AND c.status = :status
```

The condition works well and I get Child1 objects returned too.
But the parent object inside the Child1 records returned, contains all the Child2 records and all the other Child1 records with it. This is not required at all.

How do I make sure that I get only the the selected Child1 records and their parents..nothing extra. I do not want the parent to be returned with all its children.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can get rid of your childs lists in your parent and try.. and/Or dont intanciate them in your parent Class try this code :

```
@Entity
    @DynamicUpdate
    @Table(name = "PARENT", catalog = "MYDB")
    public class Parent implements Serializable {
        private Set<Child1> child1;
        private Set<Child2> child2;

        @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        public Set<Child1> getChild1() {
            return child1;
        }

    ...

        @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "parent")
        public Set<Child2> getChild2() {
            return child2;
        }
}
```

if it doesn't work, remove your lists and try again ..

Comment: Nope it does't work. And why should I remove my Set from the parent class? I want the mapping to be defined. Or maybe I didn't quite understand your statement "remove your lists and try again"

Comment: you can define the mapping if you only add an attribute in your child class with parent type `@ManyToOne @JoinColumn(name="parent_id") private Parent parent;`

Comment: I do have my parent attribute defined in my child class. Only thing is the annotations are defined in the setter of the parent. But that shouldn't be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try Changing the code of class `Child1` as following and make sure that the foriegn key column `ID` is created in the database table

```
@Entity
@DynamicUpdate
@Table(name = "CHILD1", catalog = "MYDB")
public class Child1 implements Serializable {
    ...
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    private Parent parent;

}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: By making it lazy I do not get my parent returned :/

Answer (score 0):

try this one :

```
Parent Class: 

     @Entity
        @DynamicUpdate
        @Table(name = "PARENT", catalog = "MYDB")
        public class Parent implements Serializable {

          @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "parent")
            private Set<Child1> child1;
          @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "parent")
            private Set<Child2> child2;

            public Set<Child1> getChild1() {
                return child1;
            }

            public Set<Child2> getChild2() {
                return child2;
            }
    }
```

Child Class :

```
    @Entity
    @DynamicUpdate
    @Table(name = "CHILD1", catalog = "MYDB")
    public class Child1 implements Serializable {

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        @JoinColumn(name = "ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    public Parent parent;


        public Parent getParent() {
            return parent;
        }
```

Comment: What is the difference here ? I have the same definition on my getter methods.